# How to hide address bar in lastest version of (Firefox, chrome and internet Explour) using javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to hide the address bar in the latest version of (Firefox, chrome and internet Explorer) using javascript window.open

I am using following code but it doesn't work.

```
var popup = window.open('@Url.Action("LoanTaggingErrorReport","Finance")',
'name','width=900,height=750,
toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,resizable =yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at couple of solutions on the net but nothing seems to be available for IE and Firefox working together. Then I figured it out a way to work it out for both. This is the code : 
`

```
<js>
function openWindow(){
var browser=navigator.appName;
if (browser==”Microsoft Internet Explorer”)
{
window.opener=self;

}
window.open(‘filename.htm’,’null’,’width=900,height=750,
toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,resizable =yes’);
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height-100);
self.close();
}

</js>
```

`
Note: **If the window does not open, please turn off the pop-up blocker for this site**

Comment: its also not working on chrome as well. Because the parameter of winodow.open (location = no ) is not working in any browswer